# Set reference of an abstract class by initialization list

Tags: c++, stm32

I need to call an object of a class that initializes an interface by reference, the problem is that the object is needed during runtime but doesn't exist yet.

I've tried setting it as a constexpr so that the object is created during compile time but that doesn't seem to work. The class is called ltdc and an object needs to call the contructor eg. ltdcObject(Ltdc())

```
class Ltdc : public ILtdc
{
      public:
        constexpr Ltdc() noexcept {}
};


///////////////////////////////////////

class ILtdc
{
    protected:

    constexpr ILtdc() { }       

    public:

    virtual ~ILtdc() {}
};
///////////////////////////////////////

class Ili9341 final
{
  public:

  Ili9341() noexcept;

  ILtdc & ltdc; //Interface Ltdc Reference
};


///////////////////////////////////////

Ili9341:: Ili9341() noexcept : 

    ltdc(Ltdc()) //this is where it's called in the cpp file

{ }
```

> error: #461 initial value of non-const must be an lvalue

Comment: You create dangling pointer... You probably need `std::unique_ptr<ILtdc> ltdc;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 we can't do that since we're not allowed to use external libraries

Comment: Why do you have `ILtdc & ltdc;` instead of `Ltdc ltdc;`?

Comment: @Jarod42 We were told by our professor to do that, no idea why.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make constructor to `Ili9341` take a reference to `ILtdc` as parameter and in constructor you assign it to the member variable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a reference to an existing object you can create the object itself inside `Ili9341`:

Change

```
ILtdc & ltdc;
```

in `Ili9341` to

```
Ltdc ltdc;
```

And remove the temporary object `Ltdc()` from the initializer:

```
Ili9341:: Ili9341() noexcept : 
    ltdc()
{ }
```

If you do not want make the element `ltdc` *public* inside `Ili9341` you can make it *private* and add a public get function like

```
ILtdc & getLtdc(void);
```

returning a reference to `ltdc`.

Comment: ILtdc is an abstract class and can't initialize an object
error #322: object of abstract class type "ILtdc" is not allowed

Comment: @Evil-E: You didn't mention that ``ILtdc`` is abstract, but nevertheless I've updated my answer for that case.